# Oracle - SQL Select 2 columns, where the second one all have the same ID from the first but its not equal

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update my table and what happens is, I have 3 Columns `ID_1` and `ID_2`.
`ID_1` is unique and `ID_2` not. `ID_2` is a grouping of `ID_1` and `ID_1` is a grouping of Order.

What I'm doing is saying which `ID_1`'s belong to which group (`ID_2`) while they might belong to the same order.

```
ID_1   | ID_2  | order
------ | ------|------
1      | 1     | a
2      | 1     | a
4      | 1     | a
5      | 1     | a
6      | 6     | a
7      | 6     | a
```

Now, what i want is to `update all` field `where ID_2 = ID_1 (when id_1 = 1 update all id_2 = 1) except when id_2 = id_1`

How can i do this?

Comment: What is the final result that you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you *say* you want (you didn't name the table, so I have christened it `T`):

```
UPDATE  T  
SET     ID_2 = 1  
WHERE   ID_1 = 1 AND ID_2 <> 1;
```

Comment: I think I remember previously providing you a link about how to format posts. Here it is again: [How do I format my posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). It's not that hard.  You even have a nice convenient icon `{}` that you can use to automatically format code blocks. Thank you kindly.